# Truvativ Crank housing

Tags: shimano, crankset, compact-crankset

Im repairing a friends bike and changing the crank. I have removed it and want to find a replacement

The removed item is Model: BB-06-PSPL - 113/68
Im wondering if there is a replacement Shimano model? or an upgraded part available as the bike is quite old.?

His bike is running Shimano Tiagra triple crank 9 speed. I am wondering if I could change the crank over to shimano aswell or would this not be possible due to the fittings in the crank housing.?

Thanks for you time in advanced

RD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item you removed (BB-06-PSPL - 113/68) is the bottom bracket. The 113/68 means that it s 113mm spindle length and 68mm bottom bracket length this means that it is a standard size and will be easily replaced. The PSPL means that it has a Powerspline interface with the cranks, this is a Truvativ/ SRAM proprietry system so if you wish to keep the cranks you are using you would need a replacement Truvativ cartridge.

If you are willing to change the crankset as well you are not limited in any way as long as:

- The bottom bracket is 68mm and English thread and has the same interface as your new crankset, or you could choose and external bearing set up.
- The crankset is built for the right drive train, if you have a 9 speed rear derailleur you need a 9 speed crankset as chain widths are different.
- You can achieve the same chain line as your current set up with a new crankset through selecting the right spindle length.  (this may take a few internet searches for Shimano this is available in the [Tech Docs](http://techdocs.shimano.com/) for each crankset).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you're replacing the bottom bracket and the crankset, you should be able to use whichever crankset you want provided you buy a bottom bracket with the correct spindle length to get the correct chain line.

Comment: Yes sorry changed my track of thought halfway through.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I think we will keep the same crank set and just replace the bottom bracket. I have seen halford have the exact replacement part but the also have http://www.halfords.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_storeId_10001_catalogId_10151_productId_159780_langId_-1_categoryId_210159. Would this fit aswell without changing the crankset?

Comment: @user10432 - The link is for an ISIS bottom bracket which has a different interface to Powerspline and not compatible. You're likely to get a better deal at  http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ than Halfords.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the chainset, you will need to change the bottom bracket. You can change it to a square taper Shimano bottom bracket or something more advanced like a external bottom bracket. 
(113/68) 113mm is the length and 68 is the width of the shell.